# Can't get c# linq query to compile with joins

Tags: c#, linq, join, compiler-errors

Below is a cut down example of some c# code I can't get to compile while doing some linq joins. Does anyone know why this doesn't compile?

The error is

> Type arguments cannot be inferred from the query

(In my real code `Fetch()` returns an `IQueryable<T>`)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqJoin
{
    public class DataRepository<T>
    {
        public IList<T> Fetch()
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
    }

    internal class SSOUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    internal class UserRole
    {
        public int SSOUserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Role
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var users = new DataRepository<SSOUser>().Fetch();
            var userroles = new DataRepository<UserRole>().Fetch();
            var roles = new DataRepository<Role>().Fetch();

            var result = from u in users
                   join ur in userroles on u.Id equals ur.SSOUserId
                   join r in roles on r.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                   select u;

        //var x1 = users.Join(userroles, u => u.Id, ur => ur.SSOUserId, (u, ur) => new { User = u, UserRole = ur}).Join(roles, x => x.UserRole.RoleId, r => r.RoleId, res => res.User);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This join is the wrong way round:

```
join r in roles on r.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
```

It should be:

```
join r in roles on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
```

The range variable you introduce always has to be on the *right* hand side of the `equals`. Normally the compiler is pretty good about telling you that in the error message, mind you...

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer. you wont believe how much time I've wasted on that. It would be nice if the compiler was a bit more helpful but your tip about "range variable you introduce always has to be on the right hand side of the equals" is one I will now commit to memory.