# LINQ: Why is my IQueryable.Intersect throwing an exception

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ statement, and the existing variables `IEnumerable<int> conceptIds` and `int companyId`:

```
from c in dbContext.stt_concept

let A = from compDict in dbContext.stt_company_dictionary
        where compDict.company_id == companyId
        select compDict.dictionary_id

let B = from c2 in dbContext.stt_concept
        where A.Contains(c2.dictionary_id)
        select c2.id

select B.Intersect(conceptIds))
```

However, this throws an exception with the message "Specified method is not supported". The inner exception's TargetSite property mentions `DbIntersectExpression` so I assume that something is wrong with my use of `Intersect`.

However, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb345609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the source is an IQueryable and the parameter is an IEnumerable, both containing the same type (`int`, or so intellisense leads me to believe).

Is my use of `Intersect` wrong or is it something else?

Comment: is this entity framework or linq to sql?

Comment: @Daniel - Entity Framework using MySQL's Connector/Net. I'll add a tag for it.

Comment: Why are you performing the intersection of these two queries for each item in another table, when you never use the items from that other table?

Comment: What I've shown is only a small part of a larger query. When I encountered the exception I debugged by breaking it down into smaller blocks, and the sample in the question is the most concise I can get it while still encountering the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(from c in dbContext.stt_concept
join compDict in dbContext.stt_company_dictionary 
        on c.dictionary_id equals compDict.dictionary_id
where compDict.company_id == companyId
select c.id)
.Intersect(conceptIds)
```

Isn't this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do, but when I use that code VS highlights `join` as "The type arguments cannot be inferred from thw query". Any idea why?

Comment: @awj Those columns you're joining on aren't of the same type.

Comment: Without sounding argumentative, they are. I've just gone right down into the entity model's XML and they are both of type `int`. I thought one might have been `int?`, but no, both simply `int`.

Comment: @awj Clearly the compiler disagrees with you.

Comment: As per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945178/cant-get-c-sharp-linq-query-to-compile-with-joins), I switched the order of the variables in the `join` and it works.

Comment: @awj, huh, noobish mistake, thanks for sharing the solution, updated it above.

Comment: @AD.NET - yeah, you're the noob here ;) Thanks for the alternate approach.